# set default value of custom select field on post create (wordpress PHP jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, post, contact-form-7

I'm creating a wordpress post programmatically when a user compiles a contact form 7.
The post has some custom fields, mostly input text, which was pretty straight forward to pass data to them, like:

```
if(isset($posted_data['my-field'])){
                add_post_meta( $new_ID, 'my_field_name', $posted_data['my-field'] );
            }
```

where `my_field_name` is the name of the input field in the post, and `my-field` is the name assigned to the field in contact form front-end.

Now the problem comes with a select custom field in the post (`name="ads_id"`) with two `<option>` , first has no value, second has `value="0"` .

What I tried within the contact form code, where i use jquery as well for all the logics, is:

HTML

```
<div class="hidden"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap ads-id"><select id="ads" name="ads-id" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select" aria-invalid="false" /></span></div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#ads').val('0');
```

this same process works for text field but doesn't seem to work for this select, where i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the value of the selected child of the select. Try using:

```
$('#ads').children("option:selected").val();
```

Comment: as i stated i know the two possible values of it, i need to SET that to the second option or value=0